# How to fetch unique items using group by in directus.io

Tags: api, content-management-system, directus

Here is sample data. I want to know how I can fetch data with unique "make" of car in directus.io api

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "vehicle_id": 1,
        "make": "Chevrolet",
        "model": "Monte Carlo"
    },
    {
        "vehicle_id": 2,
        "make": "Chevrolet",
        "model": "Cirrus"
    }
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for `grouping`, which should solve this:

https://github.com/directus/next/discussions/751